# Download de pdf com python selenium e chrome

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Tenho um script que entra em um site pelo selenium, clica em um botao que gera o pdf no site, através do código abaixo eu fazia com que esse pdf seja baixado automaticamente, mas parou de funcionar faz algumas semanas, o que eu preciso mudar para que voltei a baixar o pdf, fiz alguns testes mas nada funcionou.

Segue meu script:

```
    **

chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        #localização dos donwloads
        download_dir = "C:/downloads"

        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
               "plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled":False,"name":"Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
               "download": {
               "prompt_for_download": False,
               "default_directory"  : download_dir
               }
        })
```

Mais do script

```
**

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\scrapy\chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://servicosonline.cpfl.com.br/agencia-webapp/#/login')
sleep(15)
print(codigo)

#Digitar email
username = driver.find_element_by_id('documentoEmail')
username.send_keys('email')
sleep(0.5)

#Digitar Senha
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
password.send_keys('senha')
sleep(2)

#Clicar botao para logar
sign_in_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@valeutype="submit"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", sign_in_button)
sleep(5)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 600).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'selInstalacao')))

#Localizar botão Para procurar unidade
search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@type="search"]')
search_button.click()
sleep(4)

#Achar Unidades
original_dir = 'M:/Energia/Faturas Pendentes de Lançamento/Matão/{}'.format(codigos[c])
txt = 'M:/Energia/Faturas Pendentes de Lançamento/Matão/{}'.format(codigos[c])

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys('unidade')
sleep(1) # Pressionar o C
actions.perform()
sleep(2)

search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@type="search"]')
search_button.click()
sleep(4)

teste = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="ui-select-choices-row ng-scope active"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", teste)


actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys('{}'.format(codigos[c]))
sleep(1) # Pressionar o C
actions.perform()
sleep(2)


acessar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block ng-scope"]')
acessar.click()
sleep(20)

#clicar logo cpfl
logocpfl = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="navbar-logo-empresa"]')
logocpfl.click()
            sleep(10)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 360).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'btnSegundaVia')))
segunda_via = driver.find_element_by_id('btnSegundaVia')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", segunda_via)


element = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'debitosPendentes')))
pdf = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn btn-default btn-segunda-via-aberta ng-scope"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", pdf[0])
sleep(5)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'btnVerContaCompleta')))  
conta_completa = driver.find_element_by_id('btnVerContaCompleta')
conta_completa.click()
sleep(30)



driver.quit()
```

Comment: Se parou de funcionar do nada, pode ser que o site tenha alterado alguma parte do HTML..
Envie mais informações sobre seu código..

Comment: Editei e coloquei mais partes do código, mas o site faz todos os procedimentos corretamento, ele apenas nao faz o download

Comment: Seria interessante colocar o código html dessa página para poder analisar melhor.